# Why running ntpdate one after one dosnt set offset to 0

Tags: linux, ntp, time-synchronization, ntpdate

I am running ntp update , one after one (with sec between them),
In the log i see that there is always an offset , even if update was run few sec ago.

Why is that?Is there a chance to get 0 offset?

```
grep ntpd /var/log/syslog
Nov 22 15:12:01 test ntpdate[3363]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.002939 sec
Nov 22 15:12:22 test ntpdate[3368]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.002787 sec
Nov 22 15:12:47 test ntpdate[3372]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset 0.002498 sec
Nov 22 15:13:17 test ntpdate[3379]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.001611 sec
Nov 22 15:13:53 test ntpdate[3385]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.002720 sec
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty much impossible to get to a 0 offset.  Instead of using ntpdate, you should just consider running ntpd in the background.  Running ntpdate on a cron is not really the best idea for keeping your server's time accurate.